# Multiple files in program tar.gz installation package. What should I compile?

Tags: files, compiling, install-from-source, makefile

I downloaded a tar.gz file, extracted it and there are 3 files: `Makefile`, `program.c` and `protocol.h`
I've opened them in gedit and `Makefile` contains only one line `program : program.c protocol.h` 
In `program.c` i think there is a main program (lots of lines)
And `protocol.h` is only defining the main variables (only `#define` lines and `short`, `char` etc.
Should I compile only `program.c`, or `protocol.h` too?
Or compile them all?

Answer (score 0):

You don't compile an header file (altough it's possible to do so), you compile a source file which **might** include some header files, but whether the required header files have been included in the source file it's not (or shouldn't be) something up to you, it's something up to the developer: if `program.c` has been written correctly, it will list its needed header files in its `#include` statements, which will be then replaced by the preprocessor at preprocessing time with the lines contained in the corresponding header file before the compilation takes place: so to compile it just either use `make`:

```
make
```

or `gcc`:

```
gcc program.c
```

But if you really want to make sure that `protocol.h` has been included into `program.c` you can run:

```
grep protocol.h program.c
```

And if the command returns `#include "protocol.h"`, `protocol.h` has been included into `program.c`.